# Barcode app Scan result display on screen

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to make a barcode scanning app. I am stuck at the point where I am able to scan the barcode but now I want to show the barcode image along with decoded barcode number and other details on the screen and then provide a button to proceed to next screen. How should I go about it? I am unable to understand should I call an intent to new activity or the layout view. If I call the new activity, how do I pass the barcode that's decoded and other details to new activity?

Help.

Want something like this after scanning a barcode:
[image]

Comment: What's the name of the android app shown in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

you can get and use that barcode anywhere, as:

uid is a textview where i have added the result from ZXing (Zebra Crossing) library activity.:

```
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {


             if (requestCode == 0) {
                 Log.e("test 1",String.valueOf(requestCode));

                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                          Log.e("test 2",intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
                          Log.e("test 3",intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          uid.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT")) ;
                    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                          Log.e("test 4",String.valueOf(requestCode));
                    }

                }



        }
```

Comment: No no. I have already used it and I am able to scan the barcode as well. I want to know about how to display the result as shown above in the picture after scanning.

Comment: do you want to show on textview or on that gift icon

Comment: TextView. Barcode, format, date as text view along with the picture of the barcode just scanned and buttons at the bottom. Ignore the gift icon.

Comment: I have used the ZXing code from the following link. https://github.com/zxing/zxing
Can you explain your answer a lil bit. Still new to android. How do i get the image of the barcode? And do I need to add this code to a new Activity? Which class is it extending from from which I will get this override method?

Comment: i am not geeting image, i am getting the simple result of barcode, qr code as required, and my code will work on the activity wherever you startzxing library activity to get qr code screen using camera.

Comment: I want the image in particular. Rest of the stuff I am getting already. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Over Image you are seeing in sample image is a generated barcode not a actual picture captured from the camera.
For this you can use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) is a great Java PDF library. They also have an API for creating barcodes. You don't need to be creating a PDF to use it.

```
BarcodeEAN codeEAN = new BarcodeEAN();
codeEAN.setCodeType(codeEAN.EAN13);
codeEAN.setCode("9780201615883");
Image imageEAN = codeEAN.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
```